# Properties of a quotient.

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is a closed topological subspace of $B$, is the quotient map $\pi: B\rightarrow B/A$ a closed map ? I do mean that if $F$ is closed subset of $B$ then $\pi(F)$ is a closed subset of $B/A$ ? If not what should be the optimal condition on $A$ and $B$ to have a closed quotient map $\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is a subset of $B/A,$ then $D$ is closed if and only if $\pi^{-1}(D)$ is closed in $B.$

If $C$ is a subset of $B$ then $$\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))=\begin{cases}C&C\cap A=\emptyset\\
C\cup A&C\cap A\neq \emptyset\end{cases}$$

So when $A$ and $C$ are closed in $B$, then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))$ is closed, and hence $\pi(C)$ is closed in $B/A.$

This would not necessarily be true if $A$ were not closed. For example, if $A$ is not closed but has a closed non-empty subset, $F,$ then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(F))=A$ is not closed.